# While passing the char[] to JNI, the characters have some junk chars

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I passed a `char[10]` from C to Java using a `NewStringUTF`. When I print the `char` in C it is printing correctly.  When I try to print the same in Java JNI it is printing special characters:

```
䑉ㅈ‶††††††††††††††††††† †††††
```

C Code:

```
jstring acc_name =(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,account_st.name);
printf("\n Account Name: %s",account_st.name);
```

Output:

```
Account Name: Name
```

Comment: What's `account_st`?  And where is the rest of your code?  Without that, you're not going to get much beyond random guesses as to what's causing your problem.

Comment: Is the contents of your char[10] null-terminated _modified_ UTF-8? That is what NewStringUTF requires.

Comment: Actually I found the account code have some ascii characters.  How can I pass to Java?

Comment: If you are sure it is null-terminated and contains only [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/beta/nameslist/c_0000.html) (except for NUL) then it can be considered null-terminated _modified UTF-8_. Otherwise, pass it as byte[] and convert it from the encoding (Charset) that you know it to be.

Comment: You must provide the real content for the 10 bytes of account_st.name, and what kind of values may be there.